# Activity flashes up in portrait before switching to landscape

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation

I am creating an android game where every activity is set to be in landscape in the xml manifest file.

However, sometimes when going to a new activity it flashes up in portrait for a second before correcting to landscape.

Does anyone have any generic reason why this might be?

It happens when exiting the level completion screen too early which uses a ScheduledFuture

Thanks
Andy

EDIT (Manifest):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.appsolutely.sheepherder"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.appsolutely.sheepherder.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appsolutely.sheepherder.Game"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.appsolutely.sheepherder.LevelSelect" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appsolutely.sheepherder.LevelSelect"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_level_select"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.appsolutely.sheepherder.Main" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appsolutely.sheepherder.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appsolutely.sheepherder.Plague"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_plague"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"  >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.appsolutely.sheepherder.Main" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest so we can take a look?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have posted my manifest files above

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [`screenOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) to your manifest:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" ...>
```

I suggest to use `sensorLandscape` so the user can choose if the divice is rotated to the right or the left.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually already have this in the Manifest file. I've edited my original post to show the Manifest file

Comment: Did you try to call [`setRequestedOrientation(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) in your [`onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) callback?

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried that... The problem actually occurs more specifically when clicking buttons on a CustomDialog. Could this be the cause? The dialog is in portrait, maybe?