# Android landscape activity first opens in portrait then switches to landscape

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation

First of all I have already added all the solutions from this link

[Orientation Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691443/activity-flashes-up-in-portrait-before-switching-to-landscape)

I have 4 activities in my app and all of them are in landscape mode only. Flow in my app is

**Login Screen>ProductScreen>VideoScreen**

This flow works good. But there is a button on product screen which directs it back to the login activity to provide admin login functionality.

So when I click on this button, it navigates to login activity but it first shows up in portrait mode and switches back to landscape mode after sometime.

I have defined orientation both via xml as well as java class but it still happens.

All activities are opened with singleTask flag in xml.

Below is the related code

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityLogin"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And in **onCreate()** method I am doing this

```
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: can you reproduce this behavior in a simple new app ? It works totally fine for me.

Comment: @Sam I have never encountered this issue until today in any app so I think it might work properly in a new app. But is not working in this app

Comment: I can't help unless I reproduce the issue at my end. Maybe try a different phone, or try to reproduce it in a new app.

Comment: I am able to reproduce it on 3 different phones. But I am currently short on time to reproduce it in a new app.

Comment: @VivekMishra Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @hemanthkumar I think I did but I don't remember the solution now. Most probably it was because of launch mode defined in manifest